# Send notification on data change

Tags: android, api, kotlin, notifications, background

I m implementing an android app in which I want to send notification or an email if the data on the public api changes.

Detailed explanation-I am trying to send notification to users whenever there is a slot available for a particular service.I am checking slot availability through a public api.Now what I want is whenever there are slots available I want to send a notification even if the app is closed.In other words I want to keep track of the data fetched from api and when there is a change(slots available) in data ,I want to notify users

Comment: Use workmanager api https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try.One more thing should I keep requesting for new data in background?And after how much time should I do this periodic request so it does not halter's app performance